# Kotlin Data Class Property: Multiple types

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, can a property of a data class have multiple types? For example:

val CurrentValue: Double?|String
or
val CurrentValue: String|Array?

I cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin and discriminated unions (sum types)](//stackoverflow.com/q/28695254/90527)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Union types are not a thing in Kotlin.

You may use a `sealed class` instead.

```kotlin
sealed class CurrentValue<T>(val value: T) {
  class TextualValue(value: String) : CurrentValue<String>(value)
  class NumericValue(value: Double) : CurrentValue<Double>(value)
}
```

Which then you can use exhaustive `when` expressions (similar to `switch` in other languages) in order to access the value in a type-safe manner:

```kotlin
fun doSomething(value: CurrentValue<*>) {
  
  when(value) {
    is TextualValue -> value.value // is recognised as a String
    is NumericValue -> value.value // is recognised as a Double
  }

}
```

If creating a type is way too much for you then you can perform a `when` statement and treat a parameter based on it's type and perhaps normalize it:

```kotlin
fun parseValue(value: Any?): Double? = when(value){
  is Double -> value
  is String -> value.toDoubleOrNull()
  is Int -> value.toDouble()
  else -> null
}
```

Comment: this is a pretty nice way of using a sealed class, great answer

Comment: Still have to see a language that allows so much flexibility while maintaining a strong type system. Kotlin is amazing

Comment: there is an error. "One type argument expected for class CurrentValue<T>" in where class defined on CurrentValue : class TextualValue(value: String) : CurrentValue(value) 

I edited your answer a little.